# can "Ok" be used as adverb in "I am doing OK?"

Tags: word-usage

When watching American movie, I often hear "I am doing OK?".

Normally "Ok" is adjective as in "I am Ok".

So, can "Ok" be used as adverb in "I am doing OK?".

Comment: Did you check any [dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/OK) to see if you can use it as an adverb?

Comment: Are you sure that it would be an adverb in that position? In *I’m doing well*, the last word is an adjective.

Comment: @tchrist "the last word is an adjective" - [no, it's not](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/well)

Comment: @Kreiri It most certainly is:  “You may be sick today, but tomorrow shall find you a **well** man.” That’s because  *well* is an adjective meaning healthy and fit.  One does not complete sentences like “I am X” using adverbs, but rather using adjectives.

Comment: @tchrist "I'm well" - "well" is an *adjective*, modifying *pronoun* "I". "I'm doing well" - "well" is an *adverb*, modifying *verb* "am doing". See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/608/18195

Comment: so how would it be "I'm doing fine" yet "I'm cutting finely", for instance ?

Comment: I am pretty sure I heard the saying"I am doing OK" in the movie. 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, OK can be used as an adverb such as he sings OK, my television works OK despite its age (The Free Dictionary). Did you sleep 0K? (Cambridge). So it's correct if you say I am doing OK.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OK (or okay) can function as an adverb (meaning in a satisfactory manner or to a satisfactory extent) or an adjective.

Actually, it can be the exclamation, the noun, the adjective, the adverb, and even the verb:

> They OK'd the resolution.